# PHP: Validate form input (add to cart)

Tags: php, forms, validation

the forms in my onlinestore have looked like this in the past:

```
<form action="cart.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="article_number" value="12345">
    <input type="hidden" name="article_name" value="T-Shirt Summer 2015">
    <input type="hidden" name="price" value="19.00">
    <select name="size"><option>S<option>M<option>L</select>
    <select name="colour"><option>black<option>white</select>
    <input type="submit" value="Add to cart">
</form>
```

The cart.php just put the data into a session without any validation. As you can see it would be very easy to cheat with the form (save local, change price to 9.00, add colours that doesn't exist in reality etc.

So my new idea was this:

```
<form action="cart.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="article_number" value="12345">
    <select name="size"><option>S<option>M<option>L</select>
    <select name="colour"><option>black<option>white</select>
    <input type="submit" value="Add to cart">
</form>
```

I've removed the name of the article and the price to avoid manipulations here.

So what's next? Best way to validate the data?

1. `if(!empty($_POST['article_number']))`
2. Check in DB if `article_number` is valid
3. Get all available colours (in DB in field "colours" like "black,white,blue")
4. `if(in_array($_POST['colour'], explode(",",$row['colours'])))`
5. Get all available sizes (in DB in field "sizes" like "S,M,L,XL,XXL")
6. `if(in_array($_POST['size'], explode(",",$row['sizes'])))`
7. Get article name and article price from DB
8. Write data to session (to show cart)

Do i need to do more validating? `trim()`? I'm using PDO...

Thanks!

Comment: Don't store the value of articles in the HTML, as you say people could just edit every item to be one dollar. You need to store attributes (cost, size, color etc) in a database and pull the item out based on a unique identifier, ie the article_number.

Comment: Why dont you link the attributes to the items with a normalized DB design. Then you would need only to POST the article unique refID to get the right item with the right color and size?

Comment: @bub Actually it's only table with the format article_number|article_name|colours|sizes|price ... example: 1000|T-Shirt Summer 2015|white,black,blue|S,M,L,XL|19.00 ... i know i could set up extra tables for the colours and sizes but this makes no sense because there are only 10 articles and so it looks more clearer

Comment: I disagree. It always makes sense to store the data in a well done design. At the moment you have 10 items there but you dont know the progress in the future(maybe you know it). And believe me it does not look more cleaner. Absolutley not.

Comment: @bub I can edit sizes/colours directly in PHPmyadmin now. Also it lists the attributes in the order i want. Of course i could add two more tables "sizes" & "colours" but i also have to add another field for the ordering then. Editing wouldn't be easy anymore. Also all queries need joins them etc.

Comment: that is life my friend ;)